# Preventing a js function from executing when it's already been executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I prevent sendMessageAppendData() from being prepended to the 'newMessageSpace' id if sendMessageAppendData() has already been executed in the current js session.

```
function sendMessageAppendData() {
return '<table id="newMessageBox1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-radius: 3pt; width: 267px; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC">'+
           '<tr>'+
           '<td valign="top" class="font1" style="text-align: center; padding: 3pt">You are messaging <?php echo $row->firstname." ".$row->lastname ?></td>'+
           '</tr>'+
           '<tr>'+
           '<td valign="top" style="text-align: center; width: 253px; padding: 3pt">'+
           '<input autofocus placeholder="Type your message" id="responseMessage" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" class="textbox1" type="text" style="width: 185pt; height: 17px" /></td>'+
           '</tr>'+
           '</table>';
}

$('#clickSendAMessage').live('click', function() {
    $('#newMessageSpace').prepend(sendMessageAppendData());

});
```

Comment: Maybe using a cookie? Also why not use AJAX since you're using jQuery it will make your code MUCH more readable, instead of inline html strings in JS which we all know is kinda messy...

Comment: set a global variable to false and set it to true inside your  function. If the variable is true then you know the function was executed...that is my idea..you can find better one..

Comment: well because using ajax would be kind of excessive for a feature like this. I just need something simple. I think a cookie would be a good idea. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of using javascript global scopr variable

```
var Isexcuted=0;
function sendMessageAppendData() {
Isexcuted=1;
return '<table id="newMessageBox1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-radius: 3pt; width: 267px; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC">'+
           '<tr>'+
           '<td valign="top" class="font1" style="text-align: center; padding: 3pt">You are messaging <?php echo $row->firstname." ".$row->lastname ?></td>'+
           '</tr>'+
           '<tr>'+
           '<td valign="top" style="text-align: center; width: 253px; padding: 3pt">'+
           '<input autofocus placeholder="Type your message" id="responseMessage" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" class="textbox1" type="text" style="width: 185pt; height: 17px" /></td>'+
           '</tr>'+
           '</table>';
}

$('#clickSendAMessage').live('click', function() {
    if(Isexcuted==0)
    $('#newMessageSpace').prepend(sendMessageAppendData());

});
```

Comment: Since you adding a global var wouldn't it be nice to just keep its access inside the the first function and doing something like `if(Isexcecuted==0) { Isexcuted=1; return '...' } else return ''.

Comment: This is bad. Any other script what might run on this site, using the same variable would mess this thing up!

Comment: Yeah, globals should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, these are fun - try this:

```
function sendMessageAppendData () {
   console.log("I ran!");
   sendMessageAppendData = function () {}
}
```

And just for a 'super clean' suggestion..

```
var clickSendAMessageHandler = function() {
    $('#newMessageSpace').prepend(sendMessageAppendData());
    $('#clickSendAMessage').die('click', clickSendAMessageHandler );
}
$('#clickSendAMessage').live('click', clickSendAMessageHandler);
```

Essentially the same idea - you use a self reference to stop whatever it was from happening ever again.

Comment: The function basically self-destructs - that's exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: No problem.. though I admit it would be cleaner to unbind your stuff.. I'll make an edit to show what I mean.. but suicidal functions are pretty useful sometimes :)

Comment: This can easily be circumvented if you use references to your function! `ref = sendMessageData; ref();`

Comment: @Nippey - really, this wasn't a security thing.. it was just a quick "I don't want it to run anymore". If it was a security thing, then yes - it'd have to be wrapped up in a closure with some internal tooling to make sure it doesn't run again.

Comment: @pedrofurla - absolutely nothing is wrong with 'one' - in previous incarnations one had the same limitations as bind, so depending on the poster's jquery version it may not have served the exact purpose that the question needed, as it was using 'live'.. which indicates some sort of change or autocreation of element. Otherwise, yes, it would have been a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't mind the additional dependency, [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#once) has a `once` method.

Comment: Oh yeah, nice catch, jquery got a `one` for that!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little utility that you can use to make any function run only once:

```
 function onceOnly(fn) {
     var executed = false;
     return function() {
         if (!executed) {
             executed = true;
             fn.apply(this, arguments);
         }
     };
 }
```

Then, just write sendMessageAppendData = onceOnly(sendMessageAppendData);

Comment: ps- can you tell that I'm a Lisp programmer?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element doesn't already exists:

```
$('#clickSendAMessage').live('click', function() {
    if(!$('#newMessageBox1')) {
        $('#newMessageSpace').prepend(sendMessageAppendData());
    }
});
```

An even better solution is to just replace `live` with [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$('#clickSendAMessage').one('click', function() {
   $('#newMessageSpace').prepend(sendMessageAppendData());
});
```

This way jQuery makes sure it's only executed once.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.data()` to save the state.

```
$('#clickSendAMessage').live('click', function() {
    var newMessageSpace = $('#newMessageSpace');
    if (!newMessageSpace.data('prepended')) {
        newMessageSpace.prepend(sendMessageAppendData()).data('prepended', true);
    } 
});
```

And note `.live` is deprecated, you could use `.on` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer doing it all in-scope by appending the executed-variable to the function itself:

```
function testFunc() {
  if(!arguments.callee.hasOwnProperty("executed")) {
    arguments.callee.executed = true;
    //alert("First Run");
  }
  else {
    //alert("Too late!");
  }
}
```